# Returned QList without "return"

Tags: c++, qt, return, qlist

I saw a curious behavior working with QList. Follows the code:

```
QList<int> returnListTest() {
    QList<int> a;
    a.append(52);
    a.append(77);
    if (false) {
       return a;
    }
}
```

Notice, there is no return, because never enter in the "if (false)". But when I call this function:

```
QList<int> r = returnListTest();
foreach (int a, r) {
    qDebug() << "return item" << a;
}
```

I have: 
"return item 52"
"return item 77".
Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: This should at least invoke a compiler warning as it is undefined behavior to not have a `return` path for a function declared to return a value.

Comment: Yes @CoryKramer, the compiler showed the message of warning. What is strange is the fact that even without the return , it returned right. I know this is not correct, only aroused my curiosity. Just it. Thanks for the answer!